# Why do the true and false unary operators require pair-wise declaration?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, operators

According to the *C# Language Specification*:

> The `true` and `false` unary operators require pair-wise declaration. A compile-time error occurs if a class declares one of these operators without also declaring the other.

This seems like a strange choice, since these two opeators, despite having names that seem related, have distinct uses.

Complete list of uses for `operator true`:

1. It allows the type to be used instead of a `bool` in an `if`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement, and as a first operand to the ternary `? :` operator. (Relevant only if the type does not also have a matching implicit conversion `implicit operator bool`.)
2. If the same struct/class overloads the `operator |` in an appropriate way, it allows the use of short-circuiting operator `||` as well.

Complete list of [uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265/) for `operator false`:

- If the same struct/class overloads the `operator &` in an appropriate way, it allows the use of short-circuiting operator `&&` as well.

Note that `operator false` is *only* meaningful if `operator &` is overloaded by the same type. Never is `operator false` relevant for `if`, `while` etc. If you want to "negate" instances of your type, overload unary `operator !` ("not") instead.

So there seem to be legitimate uses where you need `operator true` but not `operator false`, or vice versa.

For example if I need only use (1) above, I overload `operator true` (and possibly `operator !` as well). But I might not want to overload `&`, so it is meaningless to have to write the `operator false`.

And in the opposite direction, I may design a type where I can `&` instances together, and there may be a use of a short-circuit `&&` as well, use (•), so I would overload `operator false`. But that does not necessarily mean I want my type to have `|` and `||`, much less that I require my type to be usable inside an `if`, `while`, etc.

There is no requirement to overload `|` and `&` "pairwise".

Instead of the actual restriction, it would be much more useful to specify:

> *(hypothetical)* A compile-time error occurs if a class or struct overloads `operator false` without a matching overload for `operator &`.

The way things are, people are forced (by the C# spec) to write `operator false` members that have absolutely no chance of ever being invoked.

The question: *What is the motivation or historical reason for requiring `operator true` and `operator false` to go together?*

Comment: @Habib Did the requirement _The `true` and `false` unary operators require pair-wise declaration_ make sense back in the old C# 1 days, in your opinion? I do not think it made more sense then. But I do agree that people do not use this a lot because of nullables, but it is still funny (to me) that we have this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

This is done to force programmers to choose the appropriate tool for the job. If you think that you are overloading `operator false` with absolutely no chance of ever being invoked, chances are that you should be overloading the conversion `operator bool(T)` instead.

Operators `true` and `false` are there for the most part to cover situations when `true` and `false` states are overlapping, i.e. an object can be `true` and `false` at the same time (alternatively, it could be neither `true` nor `false`).

The situation that you describe, i.e. when only `operator true(T)` needs to be overloaded, without a matching `operator false(T)`, is covered by a different mechanism - a conversion operator to `bool`. If all you need is to cover scenario (1) from your question, you override `operator bool(T)`, and use your class in statements that require a `bool` without having to do anything else.

There is a special case when you must overload `operator true` and operator `false` - namely, when you (1) have overloaded `operator &` or `operator |`, and (2) you want to use your overloaded operator in a short-circuiting expression. Note that both (1) and (2) are required: when you do not overload `operator |` or `operator &`, a single `operator bool(T)` is sufficient for short-circuiting; same goes for situations when you do not use your `operator |` or `operator &` in short-circuiting context.

In this situation language designers have several choices, none of which looks particularly clean, because some constructs that are correct individually become an error when they are used in a combination.

1. Detect that `true` and `false` are overloaded together
2. Detect that `&`, which is used for short-circuiting, is overloaded without `false`
3. Detect that `|`, which is used for short-circuiting, is overloaded without `true`
4. Detect that `true`, which is used in short-circuiting context, is overloaded without a matching `&`
5. Detect that `false`, which is used in short-circuiting context, is overloaded without a matching `|`

The worst part about errors 2 through 5 is that one component of what makes it an error comes from the code that uses your class, not from the code of your class itself.

The compiler designers chose to implement options 1, 2, and 3 (except for 2 and 3 they require both `true` and `false` to be overloaded to satisfy 1). They could have picked options 4 and 5 instead, but it wouldn't make it much cleaner, because three different conditions, one of which is beyond your control, would need to be checked anyway.

In the end, they went for the symmetry, making an implicit assumption that if you overload `true` and `false` for use in short-circuiting contexts of `&`, you might as well support the `|`, and vice versa.

Comment: The only use for `operator false` is to signal that we can short-circuit in a `&&` evaluation so that we will not need to invoke the user-defined `operator &`.