# C# - Why doesn't Object class have true operator?

Tags: c#, operators

Sorry if my question seem stupid.

In C++, this code work:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
if (foo)
    ....;
else
    ....;
```

In C#, this doesn't work:

```
Object obj = new Object();
if (obj)
    ....;
else
    ....;
```

because `Object` class cannot be implicitly convert to `bool` (obvious, no problem about that), and it doesn't implement `true` operator.

So my question is why doesn't `Object` implement the `true` operator (just check whether itself is null or not, sound easy enough)? Is it just because of code readability or something?

Comment: I think it's more of the case in c/c++ that it is testing for _whether `obj` is not null_ irrespective of whether it is an object or not, rather than _calling some magic true operator_.  e.g. `if (somePointerToCharArray)` equally passes the guard operator in c/c++ code

Comment: C++ does not have boolean data type. `if` just check if an integer value is zero or not.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan _"C++ does not have boolean data type"_ - Incorrect. http://stackoverflow.com/a/356728/585968

Comment: @MickyD Yes, sorry, I mistakenly it with C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of code clarity. A lot of design choices for C# were made with the goal that the code should be written in such a way that it is immediately obvious what it is trying to do. If you have something like:

```
Object obj = ...;
if (obj)
     ....
```

What does `if(obj)` mean? Is it checking if `obj` true? Is it checking if it is `null`? Is it checking if it is `0`? It's not clear to someone glancing at the code and necessitates the programmer to consult the C# documentation to see what this particular syntax is doing. So instead, C# has you say

```
Object obj = ...;
if (obj == null)
    ....
```

This way, it is obvious what you are trying to do.

This is the same reason why C# requires you to instantiate your local variables as well as declare them before you can use them in code. The value of an uninstantiated variable is ambiguous and depends on the compiler's configuration, so instead of forcing you to do research or perform guesswork, C# instead makes it so you have to code in such a way that your intention is clear.

Comment: So the true operator is useless in C#?

Comment: @Tr1et The `true` keyword is a boolean literal, just like `5` is an integer literal and `"Hello World"` is a string literal. And just like other literals, it's for when you want to instantiate, modify, or compare boolean values.

Comment: @Abion47: He's asking about the true operator, not the true keyword.

Comment: @Tr1et: No, you can implement the true operator to your own classes, thus allowing you `if(myInst)`.  [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33265/18192) has a simple example, as well as a discussion of the far less useful `false` operator (which is required if the true operator is implemented).

Comment: @Brian I deleted my previous comment about that keyword because it was part of a conversation that the other guy deleted all of his side. But the gist of it is that I would never encourage anyone to override the `true` keyword because it is one of those things that has legitimate uses but is abused far too often and promotes bad coding practice. Overriding the `true` keyword on any old object hides the operation it is performing and subverts the code clarity I talked about in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

The fundamental answer to your question is the one given in the accepted answer: because C# was designed to *avoid*, not *perpetuate* the design errors of C.

But more specifically: you ask why a type does not implement `operator true`. The answer to that question is: the *purpose* of `operator true` is to implement the short circuiting `&&` and `||` operators. Since there is no desire to have `object` implement either `&` or `&&` or `|` or `||`, there is no reason to implement `operator true` or `operator false`.

Answer (score 1):

Boxing.

It would really be horribly confusing for conditionals involving booleans to do the exact opposite when the value is boxed.

What do you want from:

```
object o = false; // Yes, this is legal, it makes a boxed System.Boolean
if (o) { ... }
```

For this reason it's fine for bool-like types to be tested in conditions, but not for `System.Object` which is the base class for all boxed values.